# Need to release all those elastic IP that are unassociated using boto3 in All regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, release, elastic-ip

I am using boto3 along with lamda to release the unused elastic IPs. Here I need to release all those IPs present in all regions of My AWS account.

```
def elastic_ips_cleanup():
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
    for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
        if "AssociationId" not in eip_dict:
            print (eip_dict['PublicIp'] +
                   " is not associated, releasing")
            client.release_address(AllocationId=eip_dict['AllocationId'])
```

I used the above codes however it only releases the IP in a particular region where I am executing the lambda function.

**The expected output:** It should release all the unused Elastic IPs present in all the Regions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once initialized `boto3.client` works only in specific region. By default the one you have in your `.aws/config`

You can loop through regions and reinitilize the client with specific region passing optional argument `region_name=REGION_NAME`. Then rerun yuor function, apparently.

You can use:

```
import boto3
import logging

def elastic_ips_cleanup(region):
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    # The rest of code you said you have tested already...


regions = [r['RegionName'] for r in boto3.client('ec2').describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in regions:
    logging.info(f"Cleaning {region}")
    elastic_ips_cleanup(region)
```

Comment: it would be great!!! if you give the syntax for list of all active regions..Since I am new to this ..I am not much aware of the codes.

Comment: Hi I checked with the above script still it only releases the IPs in current region

Comment: I am able to get desired output using below codes

    `client = boto3.client('ec2',region['RegionName'])
        addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
          if "InstanceId" not in eip_dict:
            #print (eip_dict['PublicIp'])
            print ("About to delete %s | in %s" % (eip_dict['PublicIp'], region['RegionName']))
            response = client.release_address(AllocationId=eip_dict['AllocationId'])`