# AWS Lambda to release elastic IP Address from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am relatively new to AWS and Lambdas. I have deployed a lambda and its API gateway. This Lambda is using the aws-sdk to describe EC2 instances. I would like to know if it's possible to use aws-sdk within the Lambda to release the IP Address from a given EC2 Instance Id. I can see in the aws-sdk documentation other methods to in example create an EC2 instance, create tags on the instance or reboot, start, stop the EC2 instance but so far in the aws-sdk documentation I don't find a method that I can use to release the IP Address from the EC2 instance. The only option I have found is in this SO question [Call aws-cli from AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513604/call-aws-cli-from-aws-lambda) that is for calling aws-cli commands within the Lambda but that seems it will require a complicated and cumbersome deployment and packaging process. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are SDKs for various languages supported by Lambda
For implementation using python SDK (boto3), refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597389/need-to-release-all-those-elastic-ip-that-are-unassociated-using-boto3-in-all-re

Comment: As an update I have found aws-sdk also has a method to disassociate the Elastic IP from the instance:  [aws-sdk reference disassociateAddress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#disassociateAddress-property) therefore it can be done using Python/Boto3 or also using NodeJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API call to disassociate elastic IP address from an instance is (in boto3):

- [disassociate_address](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.disassociate_address) - Disassociates an Elastic IP address from the **instance** or network interface it's associated with.

Once disassociated, you can then [release_address](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.release_address) to the AWS pool as to not pay for it, if you want.